Cloud Run Custom Domain does not work with Cloudflare
I'm trying to connect a Cloud Run custom domain to Cloudflare DNS proxy but haven't had any success so far. Has anyone managed to get this working? (using GCP LB is too expensive for my case).
I made it work for my first certificate after toggling the proxy off and on when the certificate was issued. And now for a second cloud run certificate it does not work as Cloudflare automatically flag it as proxy because the content already exist in the DNS list.

Hi @Jonathan Chevalier,Please share the documents you have followed.

Worked by disabling proxy in cloudflare, awaiting certificate to be emitted by the cloud run domain mapping and enabling the proxy again. For some reason the first time I did it did not work. It will usually take around 15min. Don't hesitate to delete the domain mapping and created it again. Just not sure if the cert renovation will work properly.
